# Get SSL going in MAMP Pro 3.0.6

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, mamp, mamp-pro

I have separately followed (and then reverted) the instructions here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318467/configuring-mamp-for-ssl
```

and also here:

```
http://themetaq.com/articles/configure-local-mamp-https-connection
```

and also here:

```
http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/mamp-with-ssl-https
```

I have generated the CRT file and the KEY file without any issue. I feel confident that all the paths are correct per the tutorials. But the page will not load.

Using the MAMP PRO 3.0.6 UI, in Hosts>SSL, it's not at all clear how to get past the grayed-out SSL checkbox. It is not encouraging that in the screenshot in the rather meager documentation, the SSL checkbox option is also grayed out (!):

```
http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/MAMP-PRO-3-User-Guide.pdf
```

I'd like to use the same self-signed certificate for a variety of hosts, which seems like it should be easily possible. (I have filed a ticket with MAMP, and received no response.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and I suddenly realized the reason is that you can't set up SSL using `localhost` as your hostname.  You need to have some kind of domain.  Since I'm using OS X, my computer is called something like `computer.local`, so I added that host, generated the crt/key files and then set everything up -- the SSL checkbox is available and I am able to connect with SSL.