# How do I get certbot working on MAMP?

Tags: mamp, certbot

I use the free version of MAMP as my local server environment and I would like to run HTTPS pages locally for testing purposes. I have attempted to install certbot via the instructions on [the certbot website](https://certbot.eff.org) for "Apache/macOS" and "None of the above/macOS" without much luck. Can anybody point me toward documentation on how to do this?

If somebody knows of a way to pass certbot the location of the apache directory that it should use, that could be helpful. Or maybe there's a better approach to getting a let's encrypt certificate working in MAMP that doesn't involve certbot?

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble on this post and might be curious, I was able to get SSL working on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 with the free version of MAMP 4.2.1 by following the procedures outlined in Robert's answer here:

[Configuring MAMP for SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318467/configuring-mamp-for-ssl)