# Secure, https When Live, Website Will Not Open Copy in XAMPP as http

Tags: wordpress, http, https, xampp, ssl-certificate

I downloaded a backup copy of a Wordpress website to use in my xampp server. That website has an SSL certificate on the live server and the prefix to the domain name is https//. When I try to open the copy in my local, xampp server I will type http// but the browser automatically changes it to https// and the page will not open. I know the xampp server is working because I can open other websites in it that do not have that issue. I never had this issue before. Perhaps there is a way to get that SSL certificate from the live site and somehow install it into xampp?... at least as far as that particular site is concerned? I am thinking it must be the Wordpress site copy that is causing the issue so either there's a way to accommodate it or a way to switch that off in the local copy?

Comment: You are able to access your admin panel

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your config.php file.

```
define('FORCE_SSL', false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);

define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/sitename');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/sitename');
```

Cross check your site link in admin panel setting > General

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added the code into the... well, the "wp-config.php" file. I felt sure that is the one you meant. It had similar code. Not sure what you meant when you said: "Cross check your site link in admin panel setting > General." Anyway, I added the code, fixed the URL path, and tried it in a couple of browsers. I wiped the cache and cookies, etc.

Comment: (Don't hit Enter, right?) It didn't work. In the Cliqz browser I got: Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8081. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.  |||  Tried Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Cliqz.

Comment: I had port issues. The port is not the problem here.

Comment: Chrome says:
This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
 ...and it changed it to https// from http//