# Creating a localhost version of a secure / https / SSL website

Tags: wordpress, ssl, localhost, mamp

I am trying to copy one of my websites to a localhost MAMP server for further development.

I bring you this as I am unable to access the site due to:

```
"This site can't provide a secure connection
localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"
```

I have:

Copied public_html folder to MAMP.

Copied Database Collation and Data.

Created a new user and applied this to the WP-config.

Removed the .htaccess instructions.

Adjusted the options DB to have http://localhost as 'siteurl' & 'home'.

Restarted my computer and local server.

When I go to localhost:8888 it reveals the folder I created. However, when I click it will add
https:// before the URL and give me the error.

Any help you can give would be appreciate, Jason.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318467/configuring-mamp-for-ssl

Comment: Thank you Kashif, I have trolled through about 20 different Q&A's and had no luck.

I would like to indicate that top answer written by Robert has helped bypass the SSL.

Again, Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JasonIsMyName how you solved this problem? I have the exact same problem. I don't see the top answer written by Robert?

Comment: Unfortunately @Henry31 Robert has removed his comment I think, I am also unable to view it. Are you trying to make the URL show as https or http?