# How to setup SSL on localhost using MAMP (High Sierra, MAMP 5.7)

Tags: apache, ssl, https, mamp, diagnostics

I want to apologize in advance for asking a question that has been asked before, but all the answers seem to be outdated.

I am trying to setup SSL using MAMP *(Not Pro)* to use with Wordpress.

I have followed several online tutorials, including:
[Configuring MAMP for SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318467/configuring-mamp-for-ssl?noredirect=1&lq=1)
and
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=886Pea2ljm0&t=2s

Unfortunately, I am unable to access https://localhost and receive the error `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

I have read that it could be something to do with the browser not trusting the certificate, I have gone ahead and added the certificate to my keychain and set it to "always allow", but still receive the error.

I am running OSX 10.13.6 (High Sierra, MAMP 5.7 and Chrome)

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can try managed domain, (mod_md) https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_md.html

Comment: Thank you. I might try that. I'm now just allowing Chrome to bypass the warning as it's just a local development environment.

Comment: Wy would you need SSL on a local development environment?, it also makes debugging harder, e.g. HTTP can be inspected with tools like wireshark, (especially useful for debugging encoding / escaping problems), this is nearly impossible with SSL (https)